# listView not displayed unless I scroll on it

Tags: ios, listview, react-native

I have a graphical bug on my react native app, and it appears only on iOS, not on android.

When I update the state of my application of the History screen (on startup, or when I add a ride, or when I remove a ride), the list of my ride items in history disappears (implemented using react native ListView). And I need to touch the screen to make it appear. After that, during navigation between screens, I have no issue (because I'm not rerendering the History screen).

I use redux + reactnavigation.
On startup, I use a common action "LOAD_RIDES" that I reuse in every screen reducer to update its state. Same with actions ADD_RIDE, REMOVE_RIDE.

But I discovered, that if I navigate to History on startup automatically (by asking my navigation reducer to go to History on startup), and that the update of the screen happens after, while the history screen is displayed already, I don't have this bug (of history items hidden).

Any idea how to solve this? Thanks!

```
"react": "16.0.0-alpha.6",
"react-native": "0.44.0",
"react-navigation": "1.0.0-beta.9",
"react-redux": "^5.0.3",
```

[image: UI bug: need to scroll on History to display listView]

---

to reproduce the bug, I created that repo: https://github.com/jcharlet/react_native_listview_bug

[image: project organisation]

The interesting piece is HistoryScreen where the listView is created.
https://github.com/jcharlet/react_native_listview_bug/blob/master/src/screens/history/HistoryScreen.js

The master branch shows the bug in action 
the unsatisfying_workaround branch shows that if I display the history screen before updating its state, it shows the list properly.

---

So far I tried unsuccessfully to

- scroll to 0,0 when rendering the screen using ListView.scrollTo
- to load rides again with redux when navigating to history screen
- upgrade react and react native to last versions
- generate a separate redux action for loading rides in history screen 'LR' (I otherwise use the same LOAD_RIDES action in hackDetails and History screens to update their states)

In Chrome dev tool I looked at the redux state before/after when I'm using the navigation work around (navigating to history screen before loading the rides) and when I'm not: nothing changes.

Comment: Have you tried to reload the data when History tab view appears?

Comment: how to do that? reload the data every time I navigate to the history tab? That means adding the navigation action in my history reducer to listen to that and then reload the data from my storage? I thought of it but felt like it was quite bulky..? That also means that if I navigate away from history screen and come back, it will probably scroll back to the top (or I will have to handle the scroll position in the screen's state). I'm gonna give it a try though! Thanks @Rahul

Comment: tried it but it doesn't work unfortunately :(

Comment: Please share the code so that we can get clear idea of what exactly is the issue.

Comment: it's tricky because the issue could come from multiple places redux/navigation/screen and that means to share a lot of code from my application.
ok i'm gonna try reproducing the error with minimum code and share that here

Comment: ok @Rahul I managed to isolate the related files and I created a github repository to reproduce the bug

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bug on react-native
my issue raised https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14069 , duplicate to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1831

To quote the guy who answered it:

> can be worked around by adding removeClippedSubviews={false} to the ListView. It might cause some performance issues depending on large your list is https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html#removeclippedsubviews but that's what we have been using.

(edited after comment from William on attribute spelling)

Comment: `removeClippedSubviews={false}`. This is the bad configuration to solve this issue. :(

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround by using a slight delay in setting the datasource.

When the data is loaded from a remote source in the componentWillMount method, the following code is run.
Seems to work :

```
setTimeout(function(){
       this.updateDataSource(array,newArray)
},300)

updateDataSource = (comments,dataSource) =>{
        this.setState({
            allComments:comments,
            dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(dataSource),
            isLoading:false

        })
}
```

And during the slight delay you can always show a loading screen. It is so short that it is not even visible.